# Applying for job that is different than my last job position

Tags: resume

How do I apply for a role that may not not seem related to my experience, but I think it is?

For instance, I am applying for a customer service position with the Post Office, but my last job was based on a healthcare position, dealing with patients. How do I best apply for the job and show relevant experience? I did have many years of experiences in the past working in retail, dealing with customers.

Comment: Hello, Marina, and welcome to the site. Unfortunately, if you read the community description you will notice that this style of question - asking for opinion based advice - is exactly what we _do not do_ here. The question needs to be general, and apply to a large number of people/situations. That is the purpose of building this library of questions and answers. You should try to re-write your question, and also refine the tags.

Comment: Actually there is a reasonable question locked away in here: "How do I apply for a role that may not not seem related to my experience, but is?"

Comment: Marina - I edited your question to perhaps make it a better fit for this site.  Please review it -- you're welcome to edit it more.

Answer (score 2):

While the wording of the original question is not really answerable for us, I'm going to answer the underlying, general question you have asked: **How do I apply for a role that may not not seem related to my experience, but is?**

In the case where on the surface it may not appear to be related, you need to highlight the skills and experience you used in your old role as they relate to the new role.  For example, if you worked in customer service in one industry, then there will be facets of that which will translate to other industries.

Focus on those parts that meet the criteria as laid out in the job advertisement or position description, and reduce the emphasis on things that were industry specific.  A sensible HR manager will see the commonality beyond the job title, but it's up to you to point out *how* your experience applies to the new role.